# How to make a Thought Bubble using core graphic in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I’m making various shapes of speech bubbles using core graphic.

However, I’m unsure how to make a thought bubble.

I made Rounded Rectangle from the rectangle. Do I use the same method to

make a thought bubble or is there any other ways?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use this as an initial guidance and then build on it:

[How to draw an oval speech bubble programmatically on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509348/how-to-draw-an-oval-speech-bubble-programmatically-on-iphone)

Here is **samfu_1**'s answer from that post

> I would do it in two iterations.   First get the context and begin a
>   path.  Fill an ellipse and then a custom path that encloses a triangle
>   with three lines.  I assumed the following dimensions: 70 width, 62
>   height.  Override draw rect in a subclass of UIView and instantiate in
>   a subclassed UIViewController:
>
> ```
> -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
>     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
>     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
>     CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 70.0, 50.0)); //oval shape
>     CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
>     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 8.0, 40.0);
>     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 6.0, 50.0);
>     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 18.0, 45.0);
>     CGContextClosePath(ctx);
>     CGContextFillPath(ctx);
> }
> ```
>
> Produces this in the iPhone simulator when added against a gray
>   backdrop:
>
> [image]
>
> This second code example will almost duplicate what you produced
>   above.  I implemented this using flexible sizes that could be supplied
>   to the UIView frame when you instantiate it.  Essentially, the white
>   portion of the speech bubble is drawn with a black stroke over lay to
>   follow.
>
> ```
> -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
>     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
>     CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(2.0, 2.0, (self.bounds.size.width * 0.95f), (self.bounds.size.width * 0.60f)); // set the rect with inset.
>     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //white fill
>     CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //black stroke
>     CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0); 
>
>
>     CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, aRect); 
>     CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, aRect);    
>
>     CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
>     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, (self.bounds.size.width * 0.10), (self.bounds.size.width * 0.48f));
>     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 3.0, (self.bounds.size.height *0.80f));
>     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 20.0, (self.bounds.size.height *0.70f));
>     CGContextClosePath(ctx);
>     CGContextFillPath(ctx);
>
>     CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
>     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, (self.bounds.size.width * 0.10), (self.bounds.size.width * 0.48f));
>     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 3.0, (self.bounds.size.height *0.80f));
>     CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
>
>     CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
>     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 3.0, (self.bounds.size.height *0.80f));
>     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 20.0, (self.bounds.size.height *0.70f));
>     CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
>  }
> ```
>
> [image]

**EDIT:**

Also you can refer to **Brad Larson**'s Answer in this post

[How to draw a "speech bubble" on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442126/how-to-draw-a-speech-bubble-on-an-iphone)

Hope this helps you.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: um.. i want to change the size of the spb according to the lenght of the text but i don't know how to make it ..