# How to create bubbles & arrows in iPhone help page about using buttons?

Tags: iphone, helper, drawrect

Most of the apps today provides the tutorial that teaches the user to how to use the buttons in the app. This help page is normally in black color with a little alpha value (so only the background will semi-visible) with a bubble box that contains the text to define controls and the arrow which points to the corresponding component.

Here is the sample image.. (From the app [MyThings](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/mythings-for-iphone/id537678529?mt=8))

This is the normal page

[image]

And if you swipe from bottom to top, the help view will appear like..

[image]

Here is my doubts:

- Which one is best to create the images & text in this help view? Drawing the images & texts using Core Graphics or by simply putting an UIImageView with a png image? Which one is efficient?
- There is no problem in implementing a UIImageView with a ready-made png image. From my knowledge, the problem here is the image file size and the loading time. If we consider the drawing method, my mind things about the following problems.
- Drawing a rectangle is so easy. ([Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451852/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-in-objective-c)). But what about drawing a rectangle with a curved corners?? Is there any function available that handle this case?
- Then the arrow, that points the corresponding component.. How can we find the exact point that should be pointed? (till iPhone 4S, there is no problem I hope, iPhone 5 has different height)
- How to draw this pointers from the particular position in the rectangle?

Any ideas?

Just confused!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Drawing the bubbles & arrows with CG is better, IMHO. It will work even if you change completely the app (if you draw them correctly pointing to the center of the button, for instance). With images, you'll need to have several copies for the different displays resolutions and scales. Also, you'll need to update the arrows if you change anything.
- I don't see any performance drawback. Both methods will draw the bubbles very fast. Also, think that you can cache the CG generated images for future use.
- See these questions to know how to draw bubbles:

  - [How to draw a “speech bubble” on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4444039/143097)
  - [How to make a Thought Bubble using core graphic in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060751/143097)
- It seems logical to use the center of the button each bubble point to. Your drawing methods needs to know where to point the arrow and the current orientation (if the app rotates). It should take into account other bubbles, to avoid overlap. You can divide the space in rows and columns and assign *free* space to each bubble.
- For better user experience, those bubbles should not *consume* taps. If you tap a button when the bubbles are visible, the intended action should be performed (instead of just hiding the bubbles and require a second tap).

Answer (score 2):

in your case i would refer resizable and reusable images.I also have many overlay screens in my app and i ended up wit generating 5 6 generic items arrows, label background and rectangular background image for the uilabel.

i know drawing rectangular is easy but it might be just overload sometimes.

if you want to change the direction of those arrows you can apply layer transformation to a UIImageview as following

```
        arrowIamgeView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 20);
```

and for rounded corners of rectangles i assume you could user textfields with a certain background color and set their layers' cornerradius property.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did it!!

From my one-day experience, I come to know that there is three ways to handle this situation.

- Simply creating needed images as png files and just use UIImageView to show. (But remember, you should have a same image with different resolutions. This will increase your app size).
- Second way of doing is, Showing the bubbles (or maybe a rectangle) by creating labels, text fields, etc.. with a arrow image. You may simply transform the image to change the pointing place of the arrow. (As, Ilker Baltaci said in the previous answer).
- Third way is, by Core Graphics. You can draw whatever you want here. As of my knowledge, increasing the app's size or increasing the memory consume by initializing/allocating/retaining labels & text fields, we can try this by Core Graphics.

I've three views where I want to implement this help screen facility. For just three screen, I can use any of the three method, because, there is no much difference related to performance if we use it for little-needed situaions. But I tried with the third way, because, I really don't knew anything about Core Graphics. So its just for learning..

**Problems that I faced**:

- The arrow should point the center of the button(or maybe top of the button). So finding this exact location is complex. I have used this feature only in 3 pages in my app. Each page contains maximum of 4 icons to describe. So I just hard coded the values (My another luck is, the app does not support landscape mode). But, if you want to use this feature for so many pages, you should define some arrays and a method that finds the center of icons by calculating its center with reference to, their origin, height & width, blah, blah..
- The another problem is, you should ensure that the bubbles are not overlapping anywhere. Here also, we need a global method that finds the location for each bubble. The size of the bubble depends on, the text size that is going to be placed inside it. This is more complex problem and for just 3 screens, I'm not going to define a global method with hundreds of calculations. So I again just hard coded the origin point, height & width of each bubble with reference to the *self.view*
- Last but not least.. The Arrow!! The height of arrow may vary with the bubble's place. The width of the bubble also may vary with height. Also, you should know the side & points of the bubble from which the arrow goes to the button. If you already fixed the places of the bubbles in your mind, these are not at all a problem for you.. :P

Now let's come the coding part,

```
- (void) createRect:(CGRect)rect xPoint:(float)x yPoint:(float)y ofHeight:(float)height ofWidth:(float)width toPointX:(float)toX toPointY:(float)toY withString:(NSString *)helpString inDirection:(NSString *)direction
{
    float distance = 5.0;
    float widthOfLine = 5.0;
    float arrowLength = 15.0;

    //Get current context

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Set width of border & colors of bubble

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, widthOfLine);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.9] CGColor]);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x+width, y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, x+width, y, x+width+distance, y+distance);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x+width+distance, y+distance+height);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, x+width+distance, y+distance+height, x+width, y+distance+height+distance);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y+distance+height+distance);    
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, x, y+distance+height+distance, x-distance, y+distance+height);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x-distance, y+distance);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, x-distance, y+distance, x, y);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    //Draw curvely arrow from bubble to button (but without arrow mark)

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(x+(width/2.0), y+distance+distance+height);

    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(toX, toY);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y+5.0);

    if ([direction isEqualToString:@"left"])
    {
        CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y+5.0, endPoint.x, endPoint.y, toX-10, toY);
    }

    else
    {
        CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y+5.0, endPoint.x, endPoint.y, toX+10, toY);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    //Draw the arrow mark

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);

    if ([direction isEqualToString:@"left"])
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, toX-10.0, toY-arrowLength);

        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toX-10.0, toY);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toX-10.0+arrowLength, toY);
    }

    else
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, toX+10.0, toY-arrowLength);

        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toX+10.0, toY);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toX+10.0-arrowLength, toY);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    .......
    .......
}
```

You can call this method from the `drawRect:` method like this..

```
[self createRect:rect xPoint:30.0 yPoint:250.0 ofHeight:100.0 ofWidth:100.0 toPointX:48.0 toPointY:430.0 withString:@"xxxxxxx" inDirection:@"left"];

[self createRect:rect xPoint:160.0 yPoint:100.0 ofHeight:100.0 ofWidth:100.0 toPointX:260.0 toPointY:420.0 withString:@"yyyyyyy" inDirection:@"right"];
```

And the final image will be like this..

[image]

I skipped triangle shape arrow, because this arrow type gives a handwriting effect.

Thanks to @djromero and Ilker Baltaci for your valuable answers.

My next confusion is about Drawing Texts!!!!! :P

Comment: Drawing text is the easiest of all. You can use - (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I can draw text using the above method. How can I find the size of the rect with reference to the string that I'm going to draw? Any suggestion?

Comment: I need to find the string height because I want to display the string in the center of the bubble.

Comment: CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:aFont 
                        constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                        alineBreakMode];