# Android make oval background drawable with chat corner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I know how to create oval background, I add this drawable to a RelativeLayout background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

But I want to create this drawable and the corner of a chat like this:

[image: oval image]

How can I add to this drawable the corner of the chat?

Comment: You probably have to use a `9-patch` image for this

Comment: I don´t know what is 9-patch, but I need that layout scale with text lines.

Comment: @user2983041  I have posted a solution. Let me know if that does not work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create your bubble layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Hello"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="-1.5dp"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/corner"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Drawable files

**rounded_rect.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#888" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>

</shape>
```

**corner.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="135%"
            android:pivotY="15%"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#888"/>

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This layout will scale with the text you add to the `TextView`

**EDIT**

I just now noticed that the arrow in your requirement should be pointing to the left. To get that make some small changes to your bubble layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/corner2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**corner2.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="135%"
            android:pivotY="15%"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#888"/>

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Which one did you try? the one using `corner1.xml` or `corner.xml`

Comment: @user2983041 Are you sure you used the drawable file exactly as I did? It should work.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to make a drawable of the complete Chat Bubble, including corners. Then make it a [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) so the drawable will expand horizontally and vertically without deforming.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering for the other corner of chat.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="120%"
            android:pivotY="90%"

    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/button_login"/>

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

[image]