# Android chat bubble outlined custom design

Tags: android, chat, android-bubbles

[image]

**I need to make like this design , help me if anyone know **

i followed reference from sof link is [answers for chat bubble link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974847/android-drawable-speech-bubble).but i dont know how to make custom style with outlined ui

Comment: you can achieve this by using a custom drawable outline layout

Comment: yes,  i  had done through 9 patch image. and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve by this 9patch image method through android studio.