# How to get this chat bubble in drawable

Tags: kotlin

[image]

'''

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%"
        android:toDegrees="0" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item android:left="20dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

'''

I am able to achieve left bottom tilted , but I want curved shaped on the left bottom

Comment: Here you can find many examples of how doing that: [Android drawable speech bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974847/android-drawable-speech-bubble)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="2dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="15"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="100%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                    android:radius="250dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```