# Custom popup menu android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, user-interface

Is it possible to make such custom popup Menu in android studio? (not flutter)
My actual problem is making that small "v" attach to the button as anchor. [image: The background is blurred but it doesn't matter that much if it doesn't look like that, thing is that I just want to to stick a "v" shaped type of thing at bottom to the anchor]

I tried anything I found on the internet and I can do the background color and shape with defining a style but can't implement the bottom "v" kinda thing. The background is blurred but it doesn't matter that much if it doesn't look like that, thing is that I just want to to stick a "v" shaped type of thing at bottom to the anchor
Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**

**The actual problem is attaching the small "V" shape to any of the options or buttons down there.** The drawable can be made using layer-list as dear Pawan also mentioned is his answer. Here's another example: If someone clicks the services button, the  popupMenu should look like this: [image]

As you can see, the background is the same, but **the little "V" is gone to the location of the services item/button.** I tried using popupWindow but then again some of these popup menu items have sub-menus (as shown in the first picture) and that causes some difficulties.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: look for chat bubble that are kind of v shaped from top left or right corners but you can play with the code and try to create the shape you want see this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974847/android-drawable-speech-bubble**

Comment: @SarmadAli Thanks a lot, it really helps with the drawings and I really appreciate it but I need to be able to move that v shape to the top of the achor ( for example if someone clicks one of the other bottom nav options in the picture, I need the v to stick to top of that option ). I know the popup menus in flutter work that way but in kotlin/java I couldn't find any equivalant, got any idea for that too?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a custom drawable for the background, and set is a background of the root view that holds the layout.

Drawable-Code

PS. The drawable doesn't look right, but when you set is as background it looks like required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size
                    android:width="60dp"
                    android:height="60dp" />
                <corners android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="14dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
                android:topRightRadius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Create your layout : I have used a `LinearLayout` and set its background to the above drawable. I have put `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout`, you can use other as per requirements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView 1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView 2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView 3"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sample Outputs:

Drawable shape

[image: Drawable shape]

Layout with drawable background

[image: Layout with drawable background]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a good way for the background drawing, I updated the question to make the problem more clear. I'd greatly apprecite any ideas for attaching the small "V" to the popup anchor (or popup caller button) too.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is manually changing the background drawable, whenever the selected item changes. You can create a custom view for easy handling. You can follow [this site](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) for more information on custom views.

You can create a separate drawable for the `V` shaped indicator, since it changes and the curved background of the pop-menu remains same.
Create the required drawable.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100"
    android:viewportHeight="100">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/black"
        android:pathData="m 50,100 l 50,-100 -100,0 z" />
</vector>
```

[image: Triangle Drawable]

Create a custom view layout. Here I have used `LinearLayout` with five views for the five options, you can change padding and margins according to you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingHorizontal="12dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/option1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/option2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/option3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/triangle_indicator" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/option4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/option5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

[image: Custom Indicator Layout]

Create a custom view for based on the layout

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CustomIndicator extends LinearLayout {
    private final View option1, option2, option3, option4, option5;
    private int selectedOption = 3;
    private final int indicatorBackground;
    public CustomIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_indicator, this);
        option1 = findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option2 = findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option3 = findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option4 = findViewById(R.id.option4);
        option5 = findViewById(R.id.option5);
        indicatorBackground = R.drawable.triangle_indicator;
    }

    public CustomIndicator(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public void setSelectedIndex(int index){
        // expose a public method to update the index of selected view
        selectedOption = index;
        updateSelection();
    }

    private void updateSelection(){
        // sets the background to selected view index
        option1.setBackground(null);
        option2.setBackground(null);
        option3.setBackground(null);
        option4.setBackground(null);
        option5.setBackground(null);

        switch (selectedOption){
            case 1: option1.setBackgroundResource(indicatorBackground); break;
            case 2: option2.setBackgroundResource(indicatorBackground); break;
            case 3: option3.setBackgroundResource(indicatorBackground); break;
            case 4: option4.setBackgroundResource(indicatorBackground); break;
            case 5: option5.setBackgroundResource(indicatorBackground); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Use the custom view in your layout, you may have to change dimens of layout file and height of the view according to your needs

```
<com.example.motionlayoutexample.CustomIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

Update the selection whenever the selection of bottom navigation bar changes.

```
// Whenever the selection of bottom navigation changes update the index here.
customIndicator = findViewById(R.id.custom_indicator)
customIndicator.setSelectedIndex(4)
```

NOTE :

- You may want to use proper names instead of option1, option2... for layout ID.
- You should also use enum class for selection instead of `int` for better code quality.